# Switching to {controller}/{id}/{action} breaks Redirec

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want delete my Question

Now generates /Customer/Approve?id=23, instead of /Customer/23/Approve.

I could specify direct like ~/Customer/23/Approve, instead of using and , but would rather stick to functions provided by .

Comment: can you show your try?

Comment: Try this: `return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName");`

Comment: Please show your routes.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a route without ID in routedata.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code, only if your controller has get method for that Action.
Or check your routedata if it has route with optional id as parameter.

Comment: In route.config file, where you have defined route, it must have id = UrlParameter.Optional. and your controller should have below method.

Comment: public ActionResult Action() { return view(); }